# Unable to convert classes into dex format in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, java-8, dex

I was using the older firebase version and gvr 1.30.. now when i updated the firebase version to 4.0.3 i am getting the Unable to convert classes into dex format at the end of build.

```
commandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -
```

**logcat :-**

```
stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already 
added: Lcom/google/protobuf/GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already 
added: 
Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$ActionBarDrawerToggleImplBase;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive 

E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-analytics-11.0.4\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/measurement/
processing 
com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementContentProvider.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementJobService.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementReceiver.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementService.class...
processing archive 
E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-analytics-impl-11.0.4\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/internal/
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/zzcec.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurement$zzb.class...
ignored resource com/google/firebase/
ignored resource com/google/firebase/analytics/
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.class...
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics$Event.class...
processing com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics$Param.class...
processing 
com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty.class...
ignored resource 
E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-app-unity-4.0.3\libs\.\armeabi-v7a\libApp.so
processing archive 
E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-app-unity-4.0.3\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource 
E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-app-unity-4.0.3\libs\.\x86\libApp.so
processing archive 
E:\Backup\WorkShop\VRQuiz\Source\Unity\Temp\StagingArea\android-
libraries\firebase-auth-11.0.4\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/android/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/
ignored resource com/google/android/gms/internal/
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jn.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/internal/jo.class...
processing com/google/android/gms/int<message truncated>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused due to the duplicate jar or aar files. Search all the jar's using the "grep -r "string" "path" command in terminal by using "GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader" etc and delete the duplicates by keeping only one in the unity plugins folder. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader - i didnt understand, can you please explain more on what to do in terminal

Comment: Execute:
grep -r "GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader" "UnityProjectPathOfAsset"

This command will list all jar or aar using having "GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader" (picked from stderr of console which says already added"). Keep only one jar and delete all other.

Answer (score -1):

When I deleted "gvr_android_common.aar" file, the project is building, but now app crashes.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, now I found the solution, I opened the file "gvr_android_common.aar" by the archiver, in it I opened the "classes.jar" file by the archiver, there I found the file "GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader.class" it is located here "classes.jar \ com \ google \ protobuf \ GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader.class" and deleted it. It works for me. Hope it helps.